# How to transform N-D coordinates into 2D coordinates using perspective projection

Tags: linear-algebra, projective-geometry, projection

Suppose we have a vector in N dimentions: $\vec{v}=(v_1,v_2,v_3,...,v_N)$ assuming our focal point for the projection is at $(0,0,0,...,0)$. How would we project this N-D vector into a 2D vector? I tried simplifying things and started to try to project a 4D vector into 3D and then use that projection and project it into 2D. The 4D vector $$v_{4D}=(x,y,z,w)$$
We can imagine the cross-section between $w$ and the coordinates that live in 3D space. Assuming we want the image to be mapped onto a hyperplane that is $n_w$ away from the focal point in the $w$ direction we can see that there is 2 similar triangles to which we can relate:
$$\frac{v'_{3D}}{n_w}=\frac{v_{3D}}{w}$$
where $$v_{3D} = (x,y,z)$$
and $v'_{3D}$ is the projected coordinate on the hyperplane. We can find $v'_{3D}$ with
$$v'_{3D}=\frac{n_w}{w}v_{3D}$$
Now that we have got our new coordinates we can project this into 2d using a similar procedure:
$$v''_{2D}=\frac{n_z}{z'}v'_{2D}$$
However, remember that $z' = \frac{n_w}{w}z$ and $v'_{2D} = \frac{n_w}{w}v_{2D}$
$$v''_{2D}=\frac{n_z w}{zn_w}\frac{n_w}{w}v_{2D}$$
$$v''_{2D}=\frac{n_z}{z}v_{2D}$$
This is equivalent to an orthographic projection from 4d to 3d, and has no information about the w component. What did I do wrong with the projection and how can I generalize it to higher dimensions?

If there is a general formula for projection of $N-2$ dimentions to 2D, if you can, leave it in a form of a matrix that acts on $v$

Many Thanks Josh

Comment: Apply a $3 \times(n+1)$ matrix to the vector $(v_{1},v_{2},\dots, v_{N},1)$, then you will get a $3$-vector $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$. The $2D$ vector you are looking for is $(\frac{x_{1}}{x_{3}}, \frac{x_{2}}{x_{3}})$. In the case of $x_{3} =0$ you have a point at infinity.

Comment: Actually, if the focal point is $0$ you can just drop the $1$ and apply a $3\times N$ matrix to $(v_{1},v_{2},\dots, v_{N})$.

Comment: @user3257842 if you look at the equations though if you do a double perspective it is equivalent to a perspective in the z axis and an orthographic in the w. How can I fix that?

Comment: It seems to me like perspective from $N$-d to $2D$ must always have an orthographic component.  Why is that? Perspective normally is obtained by intersecting the lines uniting a point $P$ to $0$ with a given plane. If you're in a $3D$ space, your $1D$ ray and $2D$ perspective plane almost always intersect. But the $2D$ plane is too small for that to happen in higher dimensions.  So how you get perspective from $Nd$ to $2D$ is first an orthogonal projection or "compression" from $Nd$ to $3D$, followed by normal perspective from $3D$ to $2D$.

Comment: To get an intuition on why higher dimensional to 2-dimentional perspective won't work without orthogonal components or projection, try doing a perspective from $3D$ to a "perspective-line" instead of a "perspective-plane" .

Comment: @user3257842 How are images of perspective 4d tesseracts possible then?

Comment: It's orthographic (flat) perspective relative to one axis and regular (point) perspective relative to the other three, I think.

Comment: But you get to choose and switch which axis is orthographic and which are not.

Comment: @user3257842 Ive looked online and theres orthographic - perspective, perspective - orthographic, perspective - perspective and orthographic - orthographic

Comment: By orthographic I simply mean "perspective with no depth", or infinite-distance perspective.
https://answers.unity.com/storage/temp/74544-temp.png 
How a drawing of a 4D tessarect works is they first do an orthographic projection from 4D to 3D, then a regular depth perspective from 3D to 2D.  The "distance" effects come from the 3D to 2D

Comment: @user3257842 But, if you look at a picture of a tesseract you can see that the w component "pulls" the points into the centre. The smaller cube of the tesseract is further away in the w direction

Comment: But the $x,y,z$ cubes (both the inner  one and outer one) are both orthographic. Only the $w$ component is not. So you can do a normal projection from $4D$ to $3D$ (to get the w pull), followed by an orthographic projection from $3D$ to $2D$.